# Freshman's Dream for Composite Characteristic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is easy to see that if $p$ is prime, then $p$ divides the binomial coefficient $\binom p k$ when $1\leq k\leq p-1$. I am guessing that this fails for all composite integers, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it. Can I have some hints, please?

Comment: If $n = p^k$, consider $\binom{n}{p}$. If $n$ is not a prime power, consider $\binom{n}{p^k}$, where $p$ divides $n$, and $k$ is the exponent of $p$ in the factorisation of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be a composite number and $p$ be the smallest prime that divides $n$. Then
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{p} = \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!} = \frac{n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times (n - p + 1)}{p \times (p-1) \times \cdots \times 2 \times 1} = \frac{m \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times (n - p + 1)}{(p-1) \times \cdots \times 2 \times 1}
\end{equation}
where $m = n/p$. If $n$ divides this then the numerator is divisible by $n = mp$ and so $(n-1)\times \cdots \times (n-p+1)$ must be divisible by $p$. This can't happen because $p$ divides $n$ and the largest multiple of $p$ less than $n$ is therefore $n-p$.

However you still get $n \mid \binom{n}{m}$ if $(n, m) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** [Lucas Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_theorem). You can also look at Andrew's generalization, for prime powers.